# iOS simulator OpenGL depth buffer issue

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl, simulator, depth-buffer

When running my OpenGL1 app on the simulator, very close positioned polygons flicker/merge into one another (the z value isn't right for these pixels). My machine is an old Mac mini.

Seems this only happens in the simulator and everything is fine on the actual device. Does anyone now why? Does the simulator use a depth buffer with a lower bit depth than the iPhone?

Comment: The simulator isn't all that similar to a real device when it comes to OpenGL. The first OpenGL app I tried runs fine in the simulator, and causes a system crash on a real device. Anyway, while it's not that surprising that you get different behavior, it might be an indication that you're borderline on depth precision. What kind of projection are you using? If you use one of the common projections, what are your near and far planes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact precision errors you'll see vary from PowerVR model to model as a lot of it is how internal working values accumulate rather than necessarily the precision at which the final values are stored; I'd guess the simulator is acting correctly within the requirements placed upon it — a buffer of the specified depth, with values calculated as required by the spec — but just happens to make different rounding errors.

The simulator in general isn't an emulator.

Comment: If everything is displaying correctly on an iPhone 4, is it most likely that it displays correctly on all iOS devices?

Comment: I honestly couldn't tell you exactly; I am aware that when I was last poking about with accuracy issues, my iPad 3, iPhone 5 and the simulator produced differing output but in those cases the simulator got it 'right' and the other two devices showed different rounding errors. Is there nothing you can do with `glPolygonOffset` to alleviate your problem regardless?

Comment: The other thing you should do is keep the near and far planes of your view frustum as close together as possible. Make the near value as large as you can (and the far value as small as you can) without clipping geometry.